# What are the dimensions of the head of a thunderbolt cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, thunderbolt

I am wondering what the dimensions of the head of the thunderbolt cable is and what the size of the input port is.

Are these standard ports or documented by Apple or do we just need to put calipers to a bunch of cables and report what gets shipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Thunderbolt 1 and 2:

[image]
<sub>(source: [staticworld.net](http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2013/09/thunderbolt-connector-100054566-large.jpeg))</sub>

7.4mmx4.5mm male, 8.3x5.4mm female

## Thunderbolt 3:

[image]

8.3mmx2.5mm male